# "Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined" error when iterating through divs - Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to toggle 5 circles (divs with class 'circle') on a page to change background color on a click with eventListener.

javascript:

```
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for(var i = 0; i < circle.length; i++){
 circle[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
 circle[i].classList.toggle('effect');
});

}
```

I keep getting the error "Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined" - I'm not sure why circle is undefined?

css:

```
.circle {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: solid 3px black;
border-radius: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 1%;
}


.effect {
background-color: green;
border-color: blue;

}
```

html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="circle">
  </div>

  <div class="circle">
  </div>


  <div class="circle">
  </div>

  <div class="circle">
  </div>

  <div class="circle">
  </div>


 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's your `circle.length` ? paste html as well with class `circle`

Comment: your html......?

Answer (score 1):

The callback you pass into the `addEventListener` captures the varible `i` in the loop, so when it is time for the callback to be executed (the `click` event is triggered) the call back just sees the varible i at the time the loop finishes which is your `circle.length`, so `circle[i]` will be out of bound which returns a non existing element (or `undefined`). So to make it work, change `circle[i]` inside the back to `this` which points to the current DOM element like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
     circle[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         this.classList.toggle('effect');
});
```

Learn more about this [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `click` event will happen in future, but the `i` to be update with the last value as loop will not wait to execute.

```
var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for (var i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
  // Creating a closure & passing value of i which is received in argument x
  (function(x) {
    // adding the click event to the the element 
    circle[x].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // this will refer to the current element in target
      this.classList.toggle('effect')
    })

  }(i)) // passing the value of i
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/15evzee5/)